# What is the difference between double and spy?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm reading about [spies](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-5/docs/basics/spies) and I can't see de difference between this:

```
RSpec.describe "have_received" do
  it "passes when the message has been received" do
    invitation = spy('invitation', deliver: "ok")
    invitation.deliver
    expect(invitation).to have_received(:deliver)
  end
end
```

And this:

```
RSpec.describe "have_received" do
  it "passes when the message has been received" do
    invitation = double('invitation', deliver: "ok")
    invitation.deliver
    expect(invitation).to have_received(:deliver)
  end
end
```

Both examples passes without problem. I can't see any advantage using `spy`

Comment: I haven't tried this out and may be wrong, but I suspect that in the spy example you could call `invitation=spy('invitation')` and be able to call `.deliver` without saying `deliver: "ok"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @max said in comments, the difference is that I can use `spy` without say `deliver: "ok"`. So, running this:

```
RSpec.describe "have_received" do
  it "passes when the message has been received" do
    invitation = spy('invitation')
    invitation.deliver
    expect(invitation).to have_received(:deliver)
  end
end

RSpec.describe "have_received" do
  it "passes when the message has been received" do
    invitation = double('invitation')
    invitation.deliver
    expect(invitation).to have_received(:deliver)
  end
end
```

The first example will pass but not the second.

[image]

Now I understand what this means...

*"You can use any test double (or partial double) as a spy, but the double must be setup to spy on the messages you care about. Spies automatically spy on all messages, or you can allow a message to spy on it."*